# PhpStorm Setting up GitHub repo on a second PC

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

I am having a strange problem I have no idea where to start checking what is wrong.

I have a private repository on GitHub with which I am working from my desktop PC and everything is working fine. I can commit and push no problems.

I now need to go to the client and wish to setup the same project on my Laptop. So I open PhpStorm and click: Check out from Version Control

When I click test on my repository it says repository not found!

So I figure it could be a credential problem, so I checked my GitHub settings in PhpStorm and clicked Test and that connected successfully with my credentials.

But still when trying to check out the Repo it says repository not found!

What could this possibly be?

**UPDATE:** Added clean idea.log immediately after I tried to clone the repo and tried a test:

```
2017-07-13 13:28:36,377 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,455 [     78]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - User scale factor: 1.25 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,455 [     78]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - System scale factor: 1.25 (IDE-managed HiDPI) 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,471 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: PhpStorm (build #PS-171.4694.2, 16 May 2017 11:36) 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,471 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 7 (6.1, amd64) 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,471 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,471 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.112-b21 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,471 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.1.4\bin\phpstorm64.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.1.4\lib\boot.jar -Didea.platform.prefix=PhpStorm -Didea.jre.check=true -Didea.paths.selector=PhpStorm2017.1 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\GrootBaas\java_error_in_phpstorm_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\GrootBaas\java_error_in_phpstorm.hprof 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,471 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.1.4\jre64\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,471 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: Cp1252 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,518 [    141]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 47 ms 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,518 [    141]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2017-07-13 13:28:36,533 [    156]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2017-07-13 13:28:38,639 [   2262]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor js-nashorn-support.xml 
2017-07-13 13:28:38,686 [   2309]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor plugin-intelliLang.xml 
2017-07-13 13:28:38,998 [   2621]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-properties-support.xml 
2017-07-13 13:28:38,998 [   2621]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-java-support.xml 
2017-07-13 13:28:39,809 [   3432]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 66 plugins initialized in 1747 ms 
2017-07-13 13:28:39,825 [   3448]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: ASP (0.1), AngularJS (171.4694.2), Apache config (.htaccess) support (171.4694.2), Behat Support (171.4694.2), Blade Support (171.4694.2), CSS Support (171.4694.2), CVS Integration (11), Codeception Framework (171.4694.2), CoffeeScript (2.0), Command Line Tool Support (171.4694.2), Copyright (8.1), Database Tools and SQL (1.0), Docker integration (2.5.3.1), Drupal Support (171.4694.2), File Watchers (171.4694.2), GNU GetText files support (*.po) (171.4694.2), Gherkin (999.999), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (171.4694.2), Google App Engine Support for PHP (171.4694.2), HTML Tools (2.0), Haml (171.4694.2), IDEA CORE (171.4694.2), Ini4Idea (171.4694.2), IntelliLang (8.0), JavaScript Debugger (1.0), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4), JavaScript Support (1.0), Joomla! Support (171.4694.2), Less support (171.4694.2), Markdown support (VERSION), NodeJS (171.4694.2), PHP (171.4694.2), PHP Docker (171.4694.2), PHP Remote Interpreter (171.4694.2), PHPSpec BDD Framework (171.4694.2), Perforce Integration (2.0), Performance Testing (171.4694.2), Phing Support (171.4694.2), PhpStorm Workshop (171.4694.2), QuirksMode (171.4694.2), REST Client (171.4694.2), ReStructuredText Support (171.4694.2), Refactor-X (2.01), Remote Hosts Access (0.1), SSH Remote Run (0.1), Sass support (171.4694.2), Settings Repository (171.4694.2), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TextMate bundles support (VERSION), Time Tracking (1.0), Twig Support (171.4694.2), UML Support (1.0), Vagrant (171.4694.2), W3C Validators (2.0), WordPress Support (171.4694.2), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML (171.4694.2), hg4idea (10.0), tslint (171.4694.2) 
2017-07-13 13:28:39,825 [   3448]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: .ignore (1.7.6), CodeGlance (1.5.2), IDETalk (145.258.11) 
2017-07-13 13:28:41,135 [   4758]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=713 
2017-07-13 13:28:41,245 [   4868]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.1.4\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2017-07-13 13:28:41,307 [   4930]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2017-07-13 13:28:41,869 [   5492]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState - Registry values changed by user: 
2017-07-13 13:28:41,869 [   5492]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState -   dumb.aware.run.configurations = true 
2017-07-13 13:28:43,304 [   6927]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Cannot read scheme Default copy.xml 
java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.SchemeLoaderKt.a(schemeLoader.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.SchemeLoaderKt.access$preload(schemeLoader.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.SchemeManagerImpl.a(SchemeManagerImpl.kt:995)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.SchemeManagerImpl.loadSchemes(SchemeManagerImpl.kt:308)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.KeymapManagerImpl.<init>(KeymapManagerImpl.kt:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:128)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:100)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:128)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:100)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:228)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:128)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:100)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.a(ApplicationImpl.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:473)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:425)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:411)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.a(MainImpl.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:343)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2017-07-13 13:28:43,304 [   6927]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - PhpStorm 2017.1.4  Build #PS-171.4694.2 
2017-07-13 13:28:43,304 [   6927]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_112-release 
2017-07-13 13:28:43,304 [   6927]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2017-07-13 13:28:43,304 [   6927]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2017-07-13 13:28:43,304 [   6927]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - OS: Windows 7 
2017-07-13 13:28:43,475 [   7098]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=15, fontScale=0.0; restored: fontSize=15, fontScale=1.25 
2017-07-13 13:28:44,903 [   8526]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2017-07-13 13:28:45,062 [   8685]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2017-07-13 13:28:45,062 [   8685]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2017-07-13 13:28:45,370 [   8993]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:97 
2017-07-13 13:28:45,386 [   9009]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:11 
2017-07-13 13:28:45,464 [   9087]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:37 
2017-07-13 13:28:45,464 [   9087]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:1 
2017-07-13 13:28:45,573 [   9196]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2017-07-13 13:28:45,946 [   9569]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 82 application components initialized in 7884ms 
2017-07-13 13:28:46,077 [   9700]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 11122 ms 
2017-07-13 13:28:50,044 [  13667]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=null; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.25 
2017-07-13 13:28:50,309 [  13932]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings  - Loaded: fontSize=10, fontScale=null; restored: fontSize=10, fontScale=1.25 
2017-07-13 13:28:51,014 [  14637]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=14, fontScale=null; restored: fontSize=14, fontScale=1.25 
2017-07-13 13:28:51,014 [  14637]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=14, fontScale=null; restored: fontSize=14, fontScale=1.25 
2017-07-13 13:28:53,136 [  16759]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@2a2d04d9 
2017-07-13 13:28:54,228 [  17851]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 23 project components initialized in 889 ms 
2017-07-13 13:28:54,945 [  18568]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@75f864d6 
2017-07-13 13:28:55,523 [  19146]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader@67931c39 
2017-07-13 13:28:55,694 [  19317]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:10298 
2017-07-13 13:28:57,254 [  20877]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:1573 
2017-07-13 13:29:06,396 [  30019]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - Cloning into 'ess'... 
2017-07-13 13:29:11,934 [  35557]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - remote: Repository not found. 
2017-07-13 13:29:11,934 [  35557]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - fatal: repository 'https://github.com/unluckynelson/ess.git/' not found 
2017-07-13 13:30:09,763 [  93386]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2017-07-13 13:30:09,779 [  93402]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2017-07-13 13:30:09,779 [  93402]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped 
2017-07-13 13:30:09,779 [  93402]   INFO - Types.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl - FileTypeManager: 0 auto-detected files
Elapsed time on auto-detect: 0 ms 
2017-07-13 13:30:09,794 [  93417]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Watcher terminated with exit code 0 
2017-07-13 13:30:09,810 [  93433]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2017-07-13 13:30:10,028 [  93651]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2017-07-13 13:30:10,044 [  93667]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2017-07-13 13:30:10,075 [  93698]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2017-07-13 13:30:10,106 [  93729]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-07-13 13:30:10,106 [  93729]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped
```

Comment: could you please attach an idea.log (Help > Show log in ...) after reproducing the issue?

Comment: Thanks for checking, added the log file

Comment: Looks like there's nothing related. Did you try the same using another (new) project? You can also try the same in latest EAP build: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program